# DataGridView sorting lost on update

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting, datagridview

I work in a call center and a few years back I wrote a small app for personal use that helps me keep track of the calls/chats/emails coming in. Well it spread like wildfire and is now used by no less than 100 people. Time for an update.

I am working with data in MSSQL that updates in real time with changes happening at millisecond intervals. I have a timer refreshing a query bound to a DataGridView. One thing I have noticed is that unless I sort by a unique value such as time the sorting is lost when I repopulate the data.

How can I keep that sort order. I do have one 100% unique value called activity_id that I can use as an index.

Comment: no I am not and if it is that simple I quit.

Comment: I take it back that did it. I am an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try adding an `ORDER BY` clause to the `SQL` statement, if you don't already have one.

Otherwise, you could try sorting on the client side, after setting your `DataSource`:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["SomeColumnName"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```